# Multiplication map on tangent bundle.

Tags: solution-verification, differential-topology

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold, and $g:X\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function, and **everywhere positive**.

Consider the map $$\varphi: T(X)\to T(X)$$ by $\varphi(x,v)=(x,g(x)v)$.

**Then $\varphi$ is smooth.**

Attempt: Define $S:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ by $S(a,\vec x)=a\vec x$ and $\triangle: \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n$ by $\triangle(\vec x)=(\vec x,\vec x)$

Claim: $\varphi$ has smooth extention which is

if $(x,v)\in T(\mathbb R^n)$- Assume $X\subset \mathbb R^n$

$E(x,v)=(Id,S)\circ(Id,g,Id)\circ(\triangle, Id)(x,v)$

Clearly $E(x,v)=(x,g(x)v)=\varphi(x,v)$

Is it O.K. proof, and how one can prove it more elegantly and I didnot even use positiveness of the map $g$, why should this g must be positive?

Comment: Can we really assume $X\subset\Bbb R^n$? We should rather do the same over a chart.

Comment: @Berci Does not every manifold lie in a euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ for, $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @Berci And what do you think about positiveness of $g$. By the way it is a problem from Guillemin Pollack, 1.8-problem 2

Comment: Actually, yes, there's a theorem for embedding in the Euclidean space, but then it's a different $n$ and the tangent space should really be the tangent plane on every point. Positivity of $g$ seems not important for this exercise.